# Why am I not getting compiler warnings for buffer overflow with -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 in gcc 10.2.0?

Tags: gcc, fortify-source

Is there any change wrt to FORTIFY_SOURCE in gcc 10.2.0. I am not getting compiler warnings for buffer overflow during build but buffer overflow is detected during runtime and the program terminates.

I have set the flags `-O2 -g -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`. Previously on gcc7.3, this implementation did give me the compiler warnings as well as the runtime warnings. Now I am not getting any compiler warnings and I have just updated the gcc version.

Also for information I have -Wall and -Wextra flags enabled as well.

here is my main.cpp file

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void)
{
    char var1[5];
    char var2[9];
    printf("size of var1",var1,sizeof(var1));
    strcpy(var1,"abcdefghi");
    memcpy(&var1,&var2,10);
    printf("size of var1",var1,sizeof(var1));
    return 0;


}
```

Have been stuck on it for days so would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you show some example code where FORTIFY_SOURCE doesn't warn?

Comment: I have added the code example in the description.

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cvq78oxqf) shows warnings with gcc 10.2.

Comment: I voted to close. Can you produce a session transcript which shows the compiler version and the actual call? E.g. `$ cat overflow.c && gcc --version && gcc -c overflow.c`? I get a compile time warning with gcc 11.3.0, and @ssbssa's link shows that you must have done something different (e.g., not actually used `-Wall`). **Edit:** Although gcc 13.1 produces a warning even without the define or the `-Wall`.

Comment: I double verified my flags in godbolt and they seem to give compiler warnings. So my implementation seems to be correct. But something on my code is not making them appear when I execute them on my machine